# How to create a C++ template to pass a value in the best way?

Tags: c++, templates

I seem to remember I way to select value-pass or reference-pass of a parameter using the size of the type.

Something like:

```
void fun( check<A> a ){
    ...
}
```

Generates or:

```
void fun( A a ){
    ...
}
```

or

```
void fun( A & a ){
    ...
}
```

Depending of the size of type A and the architecture where you compile the applicacion.

Comment: I think you mean `const A&` in the latter (and possibly `const A` in the former), as the values passed in should not be modified. Otherwise the comparison just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Someone in the Lounge mentioned Boost Call Traits, which might be what you remember seeing. Added to my answer.

Comment: @GManNickG you are right, the comparison need a const, but you get the idea

Comment: I don't remember exactly but i was along 2002 year... so, not C++11

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In C++11 you can use [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional):

```
#include <type_traits>

class A { ... };

typedef std::conditional<
   std::is_trivially_copyable<A>::value && sizeof(A) <= sizeof(int),
   A, const A&>::type AParam;

// Direct usage
void f(AParam param);

// Wrap into template class
template <typename T> struct check:
   std::conditional<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T, const T&> {};

void f(check<A>::type param);
```

For C++03 compilers you could use Boost implementation - [Boost.TypeTraits library](http://www.boost.org/libs/type_traits/).

As @sehe mentioned there is also [Boost.CallTraits library](http://www.boost.org/libs/utility/call_traits.htm) that correctly implements required functionality:

```
#include <boost/call_traits.hpp>

class A { ... };

void f(boost::call_traits<A>::param_type param);
```

Comment: Which compiler do you recommend/are you using? My compiler doesn't compile this, for various reasons.

Comment: @sehe Recent versions of most popular GCC and Visual Studio support it.

Comment: @sehe For older compilers there is Boost implementation - [Boost.TypeTraits library](http://www.boost.org/libs/type_traits/)

Comment: @Rost: I recommand checking more than size. For example on GCC `sizeof(std::string) == sizeof(void*)` which is `sizeof(int)` on 32 bits systems; yet a copy of the string implies modifying a reference count in an atomic fashion! This is far from being free. In C++11, I recommend at the very least checking the `std::is_trivially_copyable` trait to avoid classes with custom copy constructors that may do an arbitrary amount of work.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Agree. I wrote it just to illustrate idea.

Answer (score 6):

What you describe doesn't *directly* exist (at least, not *standard*)

**Edit** Found what the OP was probably reffering to:

### 0. Boost [Call Traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/utility/call_traits.htm)

`call_traits<T>::param_type` is likely what the Op had in mind/remembered:

```
template<typename T> 
   using check = typename boost::call_traits<T>::param_type;

void f(check<A> param);
```

> *Defines a type that represents the "best" way to pass a parameter of type T to a function.*
>
> **Examples**
>
> The following table shows the effect that call_traits has on various types, the table assumes that the compiler supports partial specialization: if it doesn't then all types behave in the same way as the entry for "myclass", and call_traits can not be used with reference or array types.
>   [image]

You could be referring to <strike>two</strike> *three* things, AFAICT:

#### 1. `rvalue` references

I can imagine you mean that you could optimize for move semantics. E.g.:

```
struct Demo
{
     Demo(std::string&& tomove) : _s(std::move(tomove)) { }
   private:
     std::string _s;
};
```

This way,

```
 std::string a_very_large_string;
 Demo moving(std::move(a_very_large_string)); // prevents a copy
```

---

#### 2. Perfect forwarding:

Perfect forwarding is the same principle applied to *generic* situations:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

typedef unsigned int uint;

template <typename... T>
void AnotherDemo(T... args)
{
    std::tuple<T...> perfect(std::forward<T>(args)...); // optimal

    // more code using perfect, passing it by reference etc.
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    AnotherDemo(std::string("moved")); // moved
    AnotherDemo(42);                   // copied

    std::vector<double> v { 1,2,3 };
    AnotherDemo(v);                    // copied
    AnotherDemo(std::move(v));         // moved
}
```

#### 3. Meta programming:

Building on @Rost's answer, you could use meta programming to achieve this:

E.g. using a *template alias*:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T> 
   using check = typename boost::call_traits<T>::param_type;

void f(check<A> param);
```

Comment: @Rost Good point. I guess. I fixed your own answer to include the correct header :)

Comment: OK, thanks. By the way, perfect forwarding looks far from the topic. Yes, it could be done this way, but definitely shouldn't.

Comment: @Rost I agree it's a different topic. But then again, at first I was _guessing_ what the OP might have been remembering. For perfect forwarding of (potential) rvalue references, perfect forwarding is _exactly_ what you should be using. It's clearly not what the OP was after. You answer was a better match from the start :)

Comment: I believe that `boost::call_traits` is exactly what the OP was referring to. At the very least, it certainly demonstrate that size is not the only criteria.